# Difference between root collections and immutable collection in scala

Tags: scala, collections

In scala docs of collection I found following statement as :

[docs here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html)

"*The difference between root collections **(scala.collection)** and immutable collections **(scala.collection.immutable)** is that clients of an immutable collection have a guarantee that nobody can mutate the collection, whereas clients of a root collection only promise not to change the collection themselves. Even though the static type of such a collection provides no operations for modifying the collection, it might still be possible that the run-time type is a mutable collection which can be changed by other clients.* "

But I did not get what this line ,"***whereas clients of a root collection only promise not to change the collection themselves***",is saying ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider the three possibilities:

```
def foo(it: scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[Int]) = ???    
def bar(it: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int]) = ???
def baz(it: scala.collection.Iterable[Int]) = ???
```

- `foo` takes a mutable collection, and as such is entitled to modify it.
  If you call `foo`, you **must** expect as a caller that the collection is modified by `foo` (it might not, but you cannot tell). You must also as the implementer consider the possibility that the collection is modified while `foo`executes.
- `bar` takes an immutable collection. This entails two things:

  1. for the caller of `bar`: passing a collection to `bar` will never modify it and we are guaranteed that the collection will be intact when `bar` returns.
  2. for `bar` itself: it is safe when implementing the body of `bar` to take for granted that the collection won't change while `bar` is executing.
- `baz` takes a "root" collection. Unlike for an immutable collection, only point (1) holds. In other words, only the caller of `baz` has any guarantee here: passing a collection to `baz` will never modify it and we are guaranteed that the collection will be intact when `baz` returns.
  In contrast, when implementing `baz` we have no guarantee that the collection won't change while `baz` is executing, because while `baz` itself cannot modify the collection due to the lack of mutating methods on "root" collection, it is still possible that the collection is actually mutable and will be modified by another thread.

Consider this:

```
val buf = collection.mutable.Buffer[Int](1,2,3)
def baz(it: scala.collection.Iterable[Int]) = {
  println(it)
  Thread.sleep(2000)
  println(it)
}
new Thread {
  override def run() {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    buf += 4
  }
}.start()
baz(buf)
```

And the resulting trace:

```
ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In the above snippet, we create a mutable collection and pass it to `baz` which expects a "root" collection. Then we modify the collection while `baz` executes, demonstrating that `baz` cannot rely on `it` not to change while it's executing.

Comment: Nice explanation with example , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it tells you that as a client of a root collection, you don't get the guarantee that you're getting an immutable collection. It may very well be an instance of a mutable collection subclass (which implement the root collection traits). What you cannot do though (without casting) is mutate a root collection—even it if actually is a mutable collection at runtime.